# SwiftUI Tab View animation different when swiping vs next button navigation?

Tags: animation, button, swiftui, label, tabview

I'm having a problem where the NEXT button, if tapped, the Tab View will ANIMATE to become the CONTINUE button when it gets to the last 'Page View' (which is kind of nice tbh)... BUT if instead the user swipes the Tab View rather than taps the NEXT button, the button doesn't animate between label changes and instead just flicks between the two.

Is there a way to make it animate smoothly for swipe and tap, OR to just flick on both swipe and tap?

At the moment, it's weird.

```
struct WhatsNewView: View
{
  @State private var selectedPage : Int    = 0
  private let numberOfPages       : Int    = 2 // Indexed from 0
  private var buttonLabel         : String
  {
    selectedPage < numberOfPages ? "Next" : "Continue"
  }
  

  
  var body: some View
  {
    ZStack
    {
      VStack
      {
        Spacer()
    
        Text("My Application Name 2.0")
          .padding(.top, 20)
    
        Text("What's New?")
          .padding(.top, 5)
    
        TabView(selection: $selectedPage)
        {
          Page1().tag(0)
          Page2().tag(1)
          Page3().tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))

        Spacer()
        Spacer()
    
        Button(buttonLabel)
        {
          withAnimation
          {
            if self.selectedPage == numberOfPages
            {
              // Complete the onboarding process - transition view here...

              return
            }
            selectedPage += 1
          }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
      }
    }
    .tint(.gray)
  }
}
```